# C# WinForms (TcpClient) - Unable to read/write data from/to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming, asterisk, tcpclient

I realise there are plenty of articles on this but am struggling to find an explanation for this specific problem.

The server is an Asterisk PBX server which constantly writes call data to the socket.

There are currently around 10 clients connecting to the server which randomly get an unable to read/write to transport connection exception.  This could be on the first read/write on program load or 4 hours later.  There is no consistency or pattern to this problem.  The clients do not receive this all at the same time but at different times.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?  Also, because I am a noobie to network programming, what would be the best and most graceful way of reconnecting the tcp client to the server when this exception is caught?

Thank you in advance.

```
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    private Encoding encoding;

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        this.client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.100", 5038);
        this.stream = this.client.GetStream();
        this.encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

        if (client.Connected)
            BeginRead();
    }

    private void BeginRead()
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = this.client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            IAsyncResult ar = stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, OnReadComplete, buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            //Unable to read data from the transport connection caught here.
            //How to reconnect gracefully?
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle...
        }
    }

    private void OnReadComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = this.client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                //Process response here...
            }

            BeginRead();  //Read again after read completed
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle...
        }
    }

    private void BeginWrite(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(msg);
            IAsyncResult ar = stream.BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, this.OnWriteComplete, stream);
            stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            //Unable to write data to the transport connection caught here.
            //How to reconnect gracefully?
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle...
        }
    }

    private void OnWriteComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream arStream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
            arStream.EndWrite(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs? And in that case what is that error?

Comment: Forgot to mention that there are no errors being reported in the server logs.

Comment: "forcibly closed by the remote **host**".  Your problem is on the other end of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's because you forget to 'close' the 'NetworkStream' objects. If you don't do it, GC will. However, when GC collects the 'NetworkStream' objects is not deterministic, which is why you see this random behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  At what point should I be closing the NetworkStream object?

Comment: I think you should close it in your 'OnReadComplete' method. There is a guideline on how you use 'NetworkStream.BeginRead' Method. Please read more from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx), pay special attention to the "Remarks" section.